# How to skip chooser dialog without any java code changes

Tags: android

I have one image view and on click of that i get activity chooser dialog with having photos and gallery app. 
I want to skip this and want to open the image using gallery app. Please note i dont want to use explicit intent for this.

Comment: With the restrictions you've stated, you'll have to use some sort of magic.

Comment: without any java code changes? unless the user has selected the default app to be gallery app, its not possible.